# Column oriented mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I have a situation where the data I receive from my backend is column-oriented. An example of how this data looks like is this:

```
[
    { columnName: "ID", cells: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
    { columnName: "Name", cells: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] }
]
```

So far I have managed to configure my mat-table like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element | json}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

which gives me the following result:

[image: table result]

while in reality I'd like to see the table like this:

```
|------|------|
|  ID  | NAME |
|------|------|
|   1  |   a  |
|   2  |   b  |
|   3  |   c  |
|   4  |   d  |
|   5  |   e  |
```

Is there some way to adjust the matRowDef so it defines the cells property as rows? Ideally I would just like to change this in the mat-table, so I don't need to manipulate my data and later convert it back.

Comment: can you please explain what output you are expecting after using `JSON` like this..

Comment: I added an example

Comment: here is a [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1aelr?file=src/app/app.component.html)
try in this way.

Comment: Your demo is not using mat-table.

Comment: yeah i know, because i have not much idea about mat-table, that's why i create demo with simple table trying to convey approach that how you can achieve your desired output.
but still let me try with mat-tables

Comment: @user2657943 have you solved this?

Comment: I think you're going to have to transform the data (map) before passing it into the table. The table uses the number of elements in the dataSource array to determine how many rows to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by modifying the existing response as per your need:

HTML Code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

const ELEMENT_DATA: any[] = [
  { columnName: "ID", cells: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
  { columnName: "Name", cells: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] }
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = []
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

  constructor() {
    // Take Column names dynamically
    ELEMENT_DATA.forEach(x => {
      this.displayedColumns.push(x.columnName)
    })

    // Format the array as you want to display
    let newlyFormedArray = ELEMENT_DATA.reduce((array, { columnName, cells }) => {
      cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
        array[index] = Object.assign({ [columnName]: cell }, array[index])
      })
      return array;
    }, [])
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newlyFormedArray);
  }
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1buaf)