# How to convert html table to angular material data table

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, angular2-routing, angular-datatables

I am new to angular material and I have never use mat-table and mat-header etc so I have normal HTML table and I want to design it with angular material data table I have mention HTML code below.

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of label">{{head}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of keys">
      <td *ngFor="let k of key">{{k.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Its working table but now i just want to design it proper so i want it in data table.

**Edit**
[image]

This is component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    var formId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.headers = this.dataService.GetFormById(+formId).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      this.values = JSON.parse(this.data['TemplateJson']);
      this.values.forEach(da => {
        console.log(da['label']);
        let head = da['label'];
        this.label.push(head);
      });
    });

    this.servers = this.recordService.GetFormById(+formId).subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response;
      this.data.forEach(key => {
        this.values = JSON.parse(key['TemplateJson']);
        this.keys.push(this.values);
      });
    });
  }
```

Here i am mention sample array and i am getting 2 array like below i have mention.

```
 [{ type: "header", subtype: "h1", label: "School Management" }, { type: "text", label: "FirstName1234", className: "form-control", name: "text-1554701360234", value: "ronak" }, { type: "text", label: "LastName", className: "form-control", name: "text-1554701374890", value: "dumaniya"}];
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Sample data will be more helpful!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale what else should i include ?

Comment: JSON: `keys` and `label`?

Comment: I would expect as code! images are difficult to work with!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale just check question i have edited and mention image.key means value from array

Comment: @PrashantPimpale just check again might be it could be helpful

Comment: See this: Need JSON as Code so I can try with your code:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54049115/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale just take look again is it helpful please help me if possible then

Comment: @Ronal Great! Another array?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale just duplicate array which i have mention just value going to be changes

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tejpch

Comment: @PrashantPimpale How to assign my multple array to ELEMENT_DATA beacuse this.keys have dynamic array

Comment: Need to think on it you can use dynamic columns for data!

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059924/7124761

Comment: Just go through `mat-table` documentation. It's pretty straight forward

Answer (score -1):

use this table

```
<ngx-datatable
                    #memberTable
                    class="material striped"
                    [rows]="data"
                    [columnMode]="'flex'"
                    [headerHeight]="60"
                    [messages]="{emptyMessage: 'No Data', totalMessage: 'Total'}"
                    style="width: 100%"
                    [footerHeight]="45"
                    [rowHeight]="50"
                    [loadingIndicator]="isLoading"
                    [externalPaging]="false">

                    <ngx-datatable-column [resizeable]="false" prop="firstName" name="First Name" [flexGrow]="2">
                    </ngx-datatable-column>

                    <ngx-datatable-column [resizeable]="false" prop="lastName" name="Last Name"[flexGrow]="1">
                    </ngx-datatable-column>

                    <ngx-datatable-column [resizeable]="false" [flexGrow]="3">
                        <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template
                                     let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                            <button mat-raised-button 
                                    color="primary">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                            <button mat-raised-button 
                                    color="primary" >
                                Delete
                            </button>                                                        
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngx-datatable-column>
                </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: `ngx-datatable` is a third-party component. OP wanted mat-table suggestions